# Listen/register 2G 3G change on android

Tags: android, networking, 3g, listen

I know how know network type with :

```
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int network_type = telManager.getNetworkType();
```

But I want to register when the phone switch into 2G to 3G or 3G to 2G...

Anyway to do this ?

Thanks for helping me.
Regards
Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use PhoneStateListener class. He contains method `onDataConnectionStateChanged (int state, int networkType)`.

Hope its help.